# How to solve this equation involving log?

Tags: logarithms

I want to know for which natural numbers $n$ we have the inequality $n < 8\log_2(n)$.  I know the answer is $n \leq 43,$ but I have no idea how to get there.

Comment: The answer can't be 43, $\log_2 43$ is not a natural number.

Comment: Plus in $43$. It's not $43$.

Comment: I might have paraphrased the question, let me edit it

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+n+%3C+8Log(2,n)

Comment: Do you know Lambert function ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Nope. I guess this equation cannot be solved with basic math.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just going to explain the answer of Dr. Sonnhard Graubner more thoroughly.

It is well known that $\log_2 n = \frac{\ln (n)}{\ln (2)}$

So we have $$n < \frac{8}{\ln (2)} \cdot \ln(n)$$ Which is equivalent to

$$\frac{n}{\ln(n)} < \frac{8}{\ln(2)}$$

Now consider the function $h(x)=\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$, we have $h'(x)= \frac{\ln(x)-1}{\ln^2(x)}$

Therefore $h$ is increasing whenever $\ln(x)>1$, so for $x>e$. It follows that $\frac{n}{\ln(n)}$ is increasing for $n\geq 3$.

Therefore it it enough to find the first time $\frac{n}{\ln(n)}$ passes $\frac{8}{\ln(2)}$. Checking by hand (say using a calculator) you can show that for $n=43$ we have an inequality while for $n=44$ we don't.

Answer (score 2):

You can write $$\frac{\ln(2)}{8}=\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$$ and consider the function
$$h(n)=\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$$